# How to set max memory size of kotlin compiler

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin

I'm trying to compile large kotlin project that use Gradle. So I can't just edit settings of Kotlin compiler in intellij IDEA because they will be overridden.
I've tried to set `freeCompilerArgs`

```
allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin'
    apply plugin: 'idea'

    compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions {
            freeCompilerArgs = ['-Xmx10G', '-Xjvm-default=enable']
        }
    }
}
```

But it didn't help. 
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Use `+=` in place of `=` for `freeCompilerArgs`.

Answer (score 2):

According to [settings in the official gradle repository](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/buildSrc/gradle.properties#L1), the following option should be used in `gradle.properties` file:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Dkotlin.daemon.jvm.options=-Xmx10G
```